# Angular/cli issue

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

I have a strange problem with angular/cli (WINDOWS). A year ago, I installed angular on my computer and I created a new project, all fine. I've been updating angular when a new version came out (now I'm on v7). Today I have to create a new project. If I run the `ng new my-new-project --skip-install` command, everything works, but an angular project 5 is created:

[image]

Which contains the following:

[image]

I try to update my global CLI version, doing this `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

[image]

After doing this, I execute `ng --version` and I see this :

[image]

Weird, but it's fine. If I try to generate a new project, the same thing that I explained before happens. Why did this happen? Is there any way to solve it? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

My node version is 11.6.0 :

[image]

I tried as admin:

- `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
- `npm cache verify`
- `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

And the result is the same. Even restarting, it still does not work..

[image]

Comment: The last version of the CLI is not 1.7.3 but 7.2.0

Comment: try install stable version of node.js. you use beta version of node and latest AngularCli is 7.2.0 so try this

Comment: Yes, your angular/cli version is outdated. run : `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` `npm cache verify` `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: try uninstalling the CLI first, then use install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. In my `C:\` directory there was a folder called node_modules, which contain the `angular/cli` version `1.7.3`. That's why my pc didn't recognize the new version. Deleting this folder, the result is:

[image]

Thanks everyone for your time.

**P.S:**:  I found the problem doing this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) version first.
Maybe your system takes some time to update the CLI version.
Restart your computer and `run ng --v command`

Comment: Do one thing uninstall previous version of cli and install latest one